# Change the justify-content property for a particular element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to move my `<h1>` element in `flex-start` direction, so I used `align-self` to override the initial direction, but didn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  background: deepskyblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container h1 {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation a {
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/gsg/pen/epJQvv)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `<h1>` aligned at start you want to set the `justify-content` property of its' parent to `space-between`. You don't need `align-self` on `<h1>`:

```
.container {
  background: deepskyblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.container h1 {
  color: white;  
}
```

[Updated pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYeQro).